# Nuxt Sitemap Internal Server Error on Vercel

Tags: nuxt.js, sitemap, vercel

I want to create a sitemap for my SSR Nuxt project. I'm using the `'@nuxtjs/sitemap'` module for creating my sitemap. I also added some routes for testing. Works finde on localhost:3000/sitemap.xml. But when I deploy on vercel, there is always just a Nuxt Internal Server Error.

Therefore, Google can't crawl my site. Any ideas how to fix this?

nuxt config:

```
 modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/pwa',
    '@nuxtjs/sentry',
    '@nuxtjs/sitemap',
    '@nuxtjs/robots'
  ],

  sitemap: {
    hostname: 'https://mysite.at',
    gzip: true,
    routes: [
      '/dynamic-page1',
      '/dynamic-page2'
    ],
    exclude: [
      '/admin/**',
      '/admin'
    ]
  },
```

Works fine on localhost:

[image: works fine on localhost]

Error when visiting deployed site:

[image: Nuxt internal server error]

Comment: https://github.com/nuxt/vercel-builder/issues/147

Comment: Did you find the solution for this? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

As explained here: https://github.com/nuxt/vercel-builder/issues/147#issuecomment-545684389

Just add "./.nuxt/dist/sitemap-routes.json" to serverFiles array in your vercel.json config file:

```
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "nuxt.config.js",
      "use": "@nuxtjs/vercel-builder",
      "config": {
        "serverFiles": ["./.nuxt/dist/sitemap-routes.json"]
      }
    }
  ]
```